# Using a Case statement with an Int entry from a table

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, case

What is the best way to compare an Int entry from a table in a case statement?

Using SQL server 2008 R2, Visual Basic Express with LINQ to SQL.

The code I tried doesnt work:

```
Private Sub UpdateSetOpt()

    Dim db = New ACEDataContext
    Dim SRM = From q In db.Settings
              Where q.SettingID = frmMain.CurrentSID
              Select q.RollMethod

    Select Case SRM
        Case 1
            rbStandard.Checked = True
        Case 2
            rbProfession.Checked = True
        Case 3
            rbSpecies.Checked = True
        Case 4
            rbRandom.Checked = True
        Case Else
            rbStandard.Checked = False
            rbProfession.Checked = False
            rbSpecies.Checked = False
            rbRandom.Checked = False
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SRM` isn’t an `Integer` since your `From` query returns a collection of items. To get just the first, use `Single()`:

```vb
Dim SRM = (From q In db.Settings
           Where q.SettingID = frmMain.CurrentSID
           Select q.RollMethod).Single()
```

If the query actually returns more than a single value the above code will fail; you need to use `First` instead of `Single` then. Both will fail if *no* value is returned by the query. In that case, `FirstOrDefault` may be used instead (but probably isn’t appropriate in your situation).

Adding to that, your `Select Case` is a sign of code smell. You should rather create an array of all the check boxes and use the integer to map into it:

```vb
Dim checks As CheckBox() = New CheckBox() { _
    rbStandard, rbProfession, rbSpecies, rbRandom }

' Unset all checkboxes:
For Each check In checks
    check.Checked = False
End For

If SRM > 0 AndAlso SRM <= checks.Length Then
    checks(SRM - 1).Checked = True
End If
```

Comment: FYI, `Single()` will work as long as only one record is returned. It will throw an exception if more than one record is returned. If you have a chance of getting back more than one record (and you may not with this particular query), then you can use `First()` which is like `Single()`, but does not care if there is more than one record.

Comment: @Jim From the OP’s description it sounds like the result should be scalar so `Single` would be the logical choice. But you’re right, `First` is worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks guys! That was it. While at work today I was thinking how the query would return a list and not an int and this was exactly what I was needing.

Comment: I replaced my select case with your code and the line 'check(SRM - 1).Checked = True' gets an error saying check is not declared

Comment: @Underonesky: Should obviously be `checks`, not `check`. I’ve corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`SRM` in your case is not an int but `IEnumerabe<int>`.

You want the first element:

```
SELECT CASE SRM.FirstOrDefault():
```